Canonical bundles of abelian schemes
Let $A\to S$ be an abelian scheme of relative dimension $g$.
The canonical bundle is $\omega_{A/S} = \wedge^g (e^*\Omega_{A/S}^1)$, where $e:S\to A$ is the neutral section.
In the case $S$ is a field (more generally a local ring), the line bundle $\omega_{A/S}$ is trivial, cf. Chapter 4 in Neron Models by Bosch, Lutkebohmert, and Raynaud.
However in the book they actually proved the stronger result that $\Omega_{A/S}^i$ are all free.
I'd like to know when the line bundle $\omega_{A/S}$ is trivial, especially when $S$ is affine.

Have you looked at this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189767/is-the-pushforward-of-the-sheaf-of-differentials-on-an-elliptic-curve-over-a-sch

Let $S$ be a scheme and $f: A \to S$ an abelian scheme over $S$. Then, there is always an isomorphism $\Omega^1_{A/S} \cong f^* e^*\Omega^1_{A/S}$, so in particular $\omega_{A/S} \cong f^* e^* \omega_{A/S}$. As such, any condition ensuring $e^*\omega_{A/S}$ is trivial will do.
For example, if $S$ is the spectrum of a UFD, then every invertible sheaf on $S$ is trivial, so $\omega_{A/S} \cong \mathcal{O}_A$ for any abelian scheme $A \to S$.
